# Prove by induction $\forall n\in N, \sum_{k=1}^nk^3=(\sum_{k=1}^nk)^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, induction

Prove by induction $\forall n\in N, \sum_{k=1}^nk^3=(\sum_{k=1}^nk)^2$

Step 1 of Induction: Prove base case
$1^3=1^2$

Since we've proven base case we can assume
$\forall n\in N, \sum_{k=1}^nk^3=(\sum_{k=1}^nk)^2$
Is true

Now need to prove
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^3=(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k)^2$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^3=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+(n+1)^3$$
This is where I get stuck. $(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k)^2$ is kind of tricky to get into an equivalent form. I can see that $(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k)^2=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1))^2$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Try expanding $(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1))^2$ using the binomial theorem

Comment: Hint - write $(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k)^2=\left(\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: that's kind of lame the question doesn't mention $\sum k^3=[n(n+1)/2]^2$

Comment: @DylanY so you don't know that $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: It's something if I see I remember is true, but don't have memorized by heart.

Comment: Well, it's a [well known topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number) and as such it was asked before, thus it's a duplicate ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now $$(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k)^2= [(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k)+(n+1)]^2=(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k)^2+2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1)^2=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3+2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1)^2=...=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3+(n+1)^3$$

So what we want to prove is that $$(n+1)^3=2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+(n+1)^2\\(n+1)^3-(n+1)^2=2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k \\
(n+1)^2(n+1-1)=2(n+1)\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\\
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^nk$$

and the last row is the well-known formula of the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers